# remove whole img tag from a string which matches the alt value in C#

Tags: c#, image, src, alt

I have an "img tag with alt and src properties" in a string. I want to remove this img tag from it when it matches the value of alt property.

'open tag - img alt="SCHOLAR IMAGE" src="@@photo##" style="width:11%" - close tag'

I need to get this done using C#.

pardon for the inconvenience please take 'open tag - ' as '<' and ' - close tag' as '/>'.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? What you tried so far? Where did you stuck? What error you get while solving this issue?

Comment: Just as a string? in MVC? Expected input or output? What have you tried?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: want to remove whole img tag from string which matches the alt value

Comment: string match = "SCHOLAR IMAGE";
string pattern = "/<img.*?alt='" + match + "'[^/>]+>/g";
oldContent = oldContent.Replace(pattern, "<br /><br />");

I have done this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.